# Django - Modifying string representation of User object globally (outside of admin, even) for use in Model Forms

Tags: python, django

My website has many ModelForms and whenever it has a Foreign Key property to the User model, the property displayed is username. How can I change that so that the representation is, instead, the user's full name (or something else)? I am preferably looking for a global solution, which will work for all model forms from here on, but I am not discarding a fix that involves customizing each form (rather than changing the model). I am working with a userprofile extension of the user model.

The fix that I've tried so far is supplanting the **str** method in the user class. This is the snipped I have on the model class (taken from an entry of this forum, btw). This code is in the models.py file:

```
#CUSTOMIZES REPRESENTATION OF USER
def get_full_name(self):
    return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

User.add_to_class("__str__", get_full_name)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A custom user model as @pgcd suggested is probably the best choice here.

However, if you want to customise it for each form separately, then you can subclass [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) and override `label_from_instance`.

```
class UserModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return get_full_name(obj)
```

Then use your custom model choice field in your forms.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    user = UserModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a [custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) and, in your custom model, override the `__str__` method as desired. For instance:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()  # get_full_name() is a standard User method
```